# Problems with destroy() Method in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I'm having problems overriding the destroy() method in Laravel Backpack. When I try to do more, like calling an external method using cURL to an API inside the destroy() method of my entityCRUD, it stops working (and there are no errors returned).

```php
<?php

public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('delete');

    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $array_api_user_options = AdminUserJsonRepositoryData::deleteArrayData();
    $array_api_user_options['mail'] = $customer->email;
    $array_api_user_options['ke'] = $customer->api_group_key;
    $array_api_user_options['uid'] = $customer->api_user_id;

    // Instancia o Shinobi com token e group key
    $apiShinobi = New ShinobiAPIRepositoryAPI($customer->api_auth_token, $customer->group_key, $customer->user_id);
    $apiShinobi->deleteAdminUser(json_encode($array_api_user_options));

    return $this->crud->delete($id);
}
```

When I remove the line: `$apiShinobi->deleteAdminUser()` it works again and deletes my record. Can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0):

If it work without *that line*, the problem is definitely with *that line* :-)

In Chrome Developer Tools, the Network tab, you should be able to see the result of your AJAX request - and the error you're getting:

[image]

Comment: Tabacitu, It tooks 2 minutes to process it, and returns no erros, only the value 1. It removes the user, but do not runned ok the line that calls the curl api. but when I run the api in another method, like the store, it works well.

Comment: I understand. Returning "1" is perfectly fine. If it's taking too long, it's definitely because of the CURL call - try to optimize that. An option would be to do it async, not waiting for the CURL reply. But of course, if it fails the user would have no feedback on it...

Comment: OK, iam going deeper now and found another problems, I tried the custom button and it helps me also to understand more things. Now its working againg with the destroy method. thanks a lot and sorry!

Comment: Glad to help! :-)